# nuget: publish package without publishing dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I want to create a class library and publish it to artifactory.  However, I have organized my solution such that there is a public "Client" project, then an internal "Domain" project that contains business logic that I do not want to publish.

My issue is that apparently I have to publish the Domain project if the Client project depends on it. If I don't, then when I attempt to install the Client dependency in another project, I get an error stating that Domain cannot be found.

Is it possible to accomplish what I'm looking for, i.e., an entire assembly that is only accessible to another assembly in the same solution?  The key point is that I want the classes within Domain to not be accessible to other projects.  I know I could put them in the Client assembly and mark the `internal`, but I prefer the organization of having an entirely separate project, as well as not having to mark every single class `internal`.

Comment: No, basically. You *could* keep them in separate projects, mark everything internal, then use InternalsVisibleTo as a half-way house. But if you depend on public classes in Domain, those classes *will* be available to code depending on Client.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks.  follow up, is there a way to organize a single assembly such that I don't need to mark each individual class as `internal`?  something like an internal namespace would be ideal but I know that namespaces do not have access modifiers.

Comment: No, but you could easily add a unit test that checks that all the classes in a given namespace *are* internal. Just adding the internal modifier (or even leaving it off, as internal is the default for a non-nested type) shouldn't really be too painful.

Comment: You can? how do you test for accessibility? I'm not familiar with any frameworks that provide that

Comment: With reflection - use `Assembly.GetTypes()` to get all the types, and go from there.